# Kendo grid MVVM + variable columns

Tags: javascript, mvvm, kendo-grid

I have an existing kendo grid that I'm trying to convert to MVVM. The problem is that I need a variable number of columns, depending on the data.

Previously, when I had defined the grid config in JS, I could built the columns up programmatically; in MVVM however, the columns have to be defined declaratively, using a fixed JSON string. Does anyone know of any way to do this dynamically via data-bind or perhaps by getting the column attributes off of the data source?